# Yii2 redirect all action of the controller to one

Tags: yii2

I want to redirect every request coming to a controller to single action. There will be no static content - the action will handle the routing itself. Examples:

```
Controller/ => controller/index
Controller/action => controller/index
Controller/action/ => controller/index
Controller/action/dynamicparameter => controller/index
```

I tried with suggestion from Yii1 with `controller* => controller/index` but it is not working. I tried with `controller/* => controller/index` but no success too. When I give it  `controller/<action:\w+>` I am able to use controller/action but nothing more.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to play with this to reach what you actually need, if the position of action will change in url.

Try to assign everything that goes after action to some parameter.

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => 'controller/index',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<actionId:[\w\/]*>' => 'controller/index'
```

In this case you will have additional $_GET parameter called actionId that will store all after action (if you have something after action).

Examples:

```
controller1/someaction => controller/index actionId = null
controller1/someaction/ => controller/index actionId = null
controller2/actionwithparam/param1 => controller/index actionId = param1
controller3/actionwithparam/param1/param2 => controller/index actionId = param1/param2
```

Also note: in this example we have \w as a regular expression only. That means that url parts may include only A-Za-z0-9_